# You right/you are right

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I often encounter people saying "you right" instead of "you are right". Is it correct?

UPDATE. I meant I often encounter things like "yes, you right" in written form.

Comment: Those people who say *"You right"* are **wrong**. If they also say *"I right"* they are **wrong wrong wrong!**.

Comment: Chances are that these people are actually saying *You're right*, but you aren't hearing the *-'re* when it's followed by another *r* sound.

Comment: I often encounter this in written form.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: That would be dialectal then. I have a pretty limited phoneme set myself, but even I would distinguish the vowel sounds in *"you"* *"you're"*. Perhaps it's just minimalism at work, like when even native speakers say/write *"My bad"* for *"My mistake"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I also distinguish those vowels, but it's plausible that a NNS would find them easily confusable.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: NNS might find a lot of things confusing. To be honest, I think sometimes there should be a sister site to ELU where we can hive some of that kind of thing off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The written phenomenon, of 'you right' used to mean the statement 'you are right', is well documented. (many examples at [google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22yes+you+right%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Most of the examples seem to be AAVE which very characteristically drops the 'to be'.

In addition to the possibility that some instances may be EFL speakers who natively speak a language that drops the copula, there is a trend in texting/twitter to telegraphic language, where some things are dropped.

Answer (score 11):

*You right* may be dialectic or acceptable conversationally, but it is not standard written English. The standard form would be *You are right*, or informally *You're right*— perhaps the speaker is actually saying the latter but the *'re* is muffled by his or her speech or accent.

Otherwise, I would expect *you right* only in some elaborate compound construction, such as

> I've heard conflicting opinions from Mary, John, and yourself, but my research tells me she is wrong, he half-right, and you right.

Comment: +1 for a (reasonably successful) elaborate construction that's at least not out-and-out wrong!

Comment: Maybe "I've heard conflicting opinions from Mary, John, and yourself, but my research tells me she is wrong, he - half-right, and you - right." In this case the dash replaces the "are" verb.

Comment: Or, "Let's get into our positions. Me: left. You: right." :-)

Comment: Or, "Who said that? You, right?" Hey this is a fun game.

Answer (score 7):

*You right* is almost certainly a perception of someone saying *You're right*.

The contraction *you're* is pronounced /yər/, and before a word beginning with /r/ the R's would be merged: /yər 'rayt/ ==> /yəráyt/.

In many languages, the *be* auxiliary is not necessary before a predicate adjective like *right*, so

> ***You right.***

**sounds** right to native speakers of these languages (Russian, Chinese, Malay, many others), and they have to keep remembering to put in that little auxiliary. Even if it's inaudible.

Comment: Probably also acceptable in AAVE.

Comment: The contraction *you're* can be pronounced four or five different ways, depending on your dialect of English. And if you're used to hearing it one way, somebody pronouncing it a different may sound to you a lot like *you right*.