# Pronunciation of "you're"

Tags: pronunciation

Dictionaries list the pronunciation of *you're* as

- jɔː(r)
- jə(r)
- jʊə(r)

Which one is more common in British or American English?

Comment: You're missing the American pronunciations jʊr and juər. Americans who don't have the [pure/poor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Pure.E2.80.93poor_split) split are likely to pronounce it /jʊr/ to rhyme with tour and pure. I believe those who have the pure/poor split may pronounce it /jɔr/ to rhyme with more, /juər/ to rhyme with fewer, or /jɜr/ to rhyme with fur; which of these pronunciations are likely depends on which part of the country they are from.

Comment: Looking at that list above, those are **all** British pronunciations.

Comment: @PeterShor: Why don't you convert your above comments into an answer for the record? I would definitely give an upvote myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., if *you're* is stressed, Americans<sup>1</sup> who do not have the [pure/poor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Pure.E2.80.93poor_split) split pronounce it /jʊr/ to rhyme with tour and pure, and this is probably the most common pronunciation. For Americans who do have the pure/poor split, I believe it is one of the few (if not the only) words that goes all three possible ways under this split; Americans may pronounce it /jɔr/ to rhyme with more, /juər/ to rhyme with fewer, or /jɜr/ to rhyme with fur; which of these pronunciations are likely depends on which part of the country they are from. If *you're* is unstressed, the vowel is reduced and it is pronounced /jər/ by most Americans, regardless of the pure/poor split.

<sup>1</sup>Those who have rhotic accents; this excludes many New Yorkers and New Englanders.

Answer (score 6):

In American English it's normally unstressed `[jə(r)],` as I [just had occasion to remark here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58271/15299).

On occasion it can be stressed, and then it can be any of the above. I've heard them all, and more besides.

The most useful rule is that unstressed vowels in English normally become /ə/, and function words like pronouns and auxiliaries are almost always unstressed.

Comment: Pronouns are usually unstressed?  Not in subject position, **they** aren’t.  **You** always stress those.  Or at least, **I** do. They’re often stressed as objects, too. Or so it seems to **me**; what about to **you**? Plus **I** can’t imagine not stressing the possessive pronouns, whether **mine** or **yours**.

Comment: @tchrist: I would not stress numbers 1, 2, and 5 in your comment. Numbers 3 and 4 are pragmaticaly stressed, to emphasise the opposition. Numbers 6 and 7 also constitute an opposing pair.

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, you’re right: some of those don’t necessarily stress. The ones that never stress are the possessive determiners.

Comment: The two sentences you give would normally be stressed thus: _[Not in **subject** position, they aren’t](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/conics.pdf);_ and _You **always** stress those._ But ***any*** word can be stressed for emphasis; it's just that pronouns, articles, prepositions, and other function words are designed to get out of the way fast, and in a [stress-timed language](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54489/is-there-a-rule-for-the-correct-pronunciation-of-words-starting-with-ex/54516#54516) like English, that means they're reduced most of the time.

Comment: @JohnLawler I can’t seem to come up with a sentence whose possessive pronoun is anything but stressed. Can you? I mean the genitive set like *yours, mine,* and *ours*, not the possessive determiners. Possessive pronouns go anywhere nouns can go, as subjects, direct or indirect objects, or objects of prepositions, and every which way I try them, they keep coming out stressed. What am I missing?

Comment: The genitive pronouns _theirs, ours,_ etc. do get stressed more often. But they're not nearly as common as the ordinary personal pronouns, which are usually unstressed.

Comment: @JohnLawler If “the useful rule is that unstressed vowels in English normally become /ə/”, how do you explain words like *ageism, android, because, borrow, bovine, boyhood, coffee, echo, envoy, foolhardy, funny, furlough, gargoyle, guru, honey, hoosegow, maintain, memoir, nephew,
outfit, outlaw, peewee, peon, pinto, pipette, psycho, pyrite, running, Sunday, tepee, towhee, treaty, voyeur,* and *zygote* — just to name a few? Do you have a more useful ‘rule’ that explains these myriad exceptions?

Comment: If you don't like that rule, go ahead and make up your own. That's what everybody else does.